# DAX: Create a measure with many-to-many relationship

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables: **kyes** and **facts** with two relationships between them. And a want to write a measure which will count distincts lead_id`s from **leads** table with simple condition: product_key from **kyes** table and facts table should be the same.

But values in product_kyes fields of both tables aren't unique and thats a trouble. I tried to build a bridge table with unique product_kyes values and then use a USERELATIONSHIP function, but didn't succeed.

Thanks for help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have solved this issue by creating a bridge table and writing such measure.

```
Measure = CALCULATE(
                    DISTINCTCOUNT(facts_leads[lead_id], 
                    FILTER(facts_leads, facts_leads[product_key] = facts_leads[product_key]), 
                    USERELATIONSHIP(keys_utm[parameters_utm.product_key], product_key_bridge[product_key])
                   )
```

[image: modified data model with bridge table]